comparing date time entries to filter data and getting an error
I am trying to filter a dataset by time-from and time-to range. Below is my code:
def site_data(df, site_name, time_from=None, time_to=None, columns=None):
    for name in site_name:
            
        site_data = df.xs(site_name, level='site')

        if time_from is not None:
            time_from = pd.to_datetime(time_from)
        if time_to is not None:
            time_to = pd.to_datetime(time_to)
        
        if time_from is not None:
            site_data = site_data[site_data.index.get_level_values('dateTime') >= time_from] 
        if time_to is not None:
            site_data = site_data[site_data.index.get_level_values('dateTime') <= time_to]

        if columns is not None:
            site_data = site_data[columns]
        return site_data

I am getting this error:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'

I know there are rows within that timeframe. I see them when I pass None as an argument for time_from and time_to
I have tried changing this:
        if time_from is not None:
            time_from = 'pd.to_datetime(time_from)'
        if time_to is not None:
            time_to = 'pd.to_datetime(time_to)'
        
        if time_from is not None:
            site_data = site_data[site_data.index.get_level_values('dateTime') >= time_from] 
        if time_to is not None:
            site_data = site_data[site_data.index.get_level_values('dateTime') <= time_to]

The result is just an empty data frame, but no error message.

The problem is that site_data.index.get_level_values('dateTime') is returning a string. You need to convert that to a Timestamp so you can compare it.

You are doing the equivalent of this: pd.Series(['2024-01-01']) >= pd.to_datetime('2024-01-01'). The dates inside pd.Series are strings. You need to convert them to datetime. Something like this: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2024-01-01'])) >= ..., depending on what the format is. It can work the other way around incidentally: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2024-01-01'])) >= '2024-01-01' is OK. For future reference (or if that does not completely answer your question), please always add a [mre].

Aside: Why doesn't the loop use name anywhere?

Also, you have an unconditional return in the loop. So it never repeats. Why do you have a loop in the first place?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please always provide a [mre] and a traceback when asking a debugging question here.
